# C++ Search For A String Split Across Multiple Lines In a Text File

Tags: c++, string, file, search, input

I have a text file which is a trimmed hexdump of a file allocation table, which consists of many lines which look somewhat like:

```
5e7f4c962f80d36dd2eb8fc9f20780e9
36e9f5c7645900000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
...
```

In this file, I'd like to search for a specific substring of characters. There are a few obstacles with this, however. Typically, I would just use an ifstream and getline(), then apply line.find() to each line until I found/failed to find the substring. With this file, however, it's possible that the target substring will be split across multiple lines. The file is also potentially thousands upon thousands of lines long, making it impractical to trim \n characters from the text file first (it actually bogs down the text editor and leads to strange results if I try). What would be an efficient way to accomplish my search?

EDIT: I also should point out that I actually want to return the position of the matched string, so it's not possible to, say, concatenate 2 lines together at a time, remove just that concatenation's \n character, search, and iterate through if not found. If the match starts on non-whitespace character 15000, I want to return 15000.

Comment: On Linux I would `mmap()` the whole thing, then brute force my way from start to end, smartly.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the file one `char` at a time, and match that against your search.

```
std::size_t findStringInFile(std::ifstream& file, std::string& string) {
    auto it = string.begin();
    char c;

    while (file >> c) {
        if (c == '\n')
            continue;

        if (c == *it)
            ++it;
        else
            it = string.begin();

        if (it == string.end())
            return file.tellg() - string.size();
    }

    return std::size_t(-1);
}
```